# How to combine transmute with grep function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to find a way to create a new table with variables using the `rowSums()` function from an existing dataframe. For example, my existing dataframe is called `'asn'` and I want to sum up the values for each row of all variables which contain "2011" in the variable title. I want a new table consisting of just one column called `asn_y2011` which contains the sum of each row using the variables containing "2011"

**Data**

```
structure(list(row = 1:3, south_2010 = c(1L, 5L, 7L), south_2011 = c(4L, 
0L, 4L), south_2012 = c(5L, 8L, 6L), north_2010 = c(3L, 4L, 1L
), north_2011 = c(2L, 6L, 0L), north_2012 = c(1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

The existing `'asn'` dataframe looks like this

```
row south_2010 south_2011 south_2012 north_2010 north_2011 north_2012
  1      1           4         5          3          2          1
  2      5           0         8          4          6          1
  3      7           4         6          1          0          2
```

I'm trying to use the following function:

```
asn %>%   
   transmute(asn_y2011 = rowSums(, grep("2011")))
```

to get something like this

```
row    asn_y2011
 1         6
 2         6
 3         4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing with your code, `grep()` should work like this:

```
library(dplyr)

asn %>%
  transmute(row, asn_y2011 = rowSums(.[grep("2011", names(.))]))

#   row asn_y2011
# 1   1         6
# 2   2         6
# 3   3         4
```

Or you can use ***tidy selection*** in `c_across()`:

```
asn %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  transmute(row, asn_y2011 = sum(c_across(contains("2011")))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option using `rowSums`

```
cbind(asn[1],asn_y2011 = rowSums(asn[grep("2011",names(asn))]))
```

which gives

```
  row asn_y2011
1   1         6
2   2         6
3   3         4
```

Answer (score 1):

An option in `base R` with `Reduce`

```
cbind(df['row'], asn_y2011 = Reduce(`+`, df[endsWith(names(df), '2011')]))
#  row asn_y2011
#1   1         6
#2   2         6
#3   3         4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(row = 1:3, south_2010 = c(1L, 5L, 7L), south_2011 = c(4L, 
0L, 4L), south_2012 = c(5L, 8L, 6L), north_2010 = c(3L, 4L, 1L
), north_2011 = c(2L, 6L, 0L), north_2012 = c(1L, 1L, 2L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code will do what you want:

```
library(magrittr)
tibble::tibble(row = 1:3, south_2011 = c(4, 0, 4), north_2011 = c(2, 6, 0)) %>%
  tidyr::gather(- row, key = "key", value = "value") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(year = purrr::map_chr(.x = key, .f = function(x)stringr::str_split(x, pattern = "_")[[1]][2])) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(row, year) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(sum(value))
```

I first load the package `magrittr` so that I can use the pipe, `%>%`. I've explicitly listed the packages from which the functions are exported, but you are welcome to load the packages with `library` if you like.

I then create a tibble, or data frame, like what you specify.

I use `gather` to reorganize the data frame before creating a new variable, `year`. I then summarise the counts by value of `row` and `year`.

Comment: `pivot_longer` is the new and improved function replacing `gather`. More powerful and more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 <- df %>% 
  select(grep("_2011|row", names(df), value = TRUE)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(asn_y2011 = sum(c_across(south_2011:north_2011))) %>% 
  select(row, asn_y2011)
  
#     row asn_y2011
#   <int>     <int>
# 1     1         6
# 2     2         6
# 3     3         4
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(row = 1:3, south_2010 = c(1L, 5L, 7L), south_2011 = c(4L, 0L, 4L), south_2012 = c(5L, 8L, 6L), north_2010 = c(3L, 4L, 1L), north_2011 = c(2L, 6L, 0L), north_2012 = c(1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```